# Bootstrap 4 How do I initialise different types of popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I have two type of popover I want to use with Bootstrap 4. But it would seem I can initialise ALL the popovers, or I can initialise them individually;

So I can do this;

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

or I can do this;

```
$('.basket').popover({
  html: true, 
  content: function() {
    return $('#usertools_content_wrapper').html();
  }
});
```

But I can't do both, am I missing something? as I'd like SOME of my popovers to be inline, and some to be HTML orientated...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a matter of the jQuery selector you're using. Why not give each popover element a unique id? Then initialize them individually with id..

```
<a href="" id="item1" data-toggle="popover">popover element</a>
<a href="" id="item2" data-toggle="popover">popover element</a>

$('#item1').popover();
$('#item2').popover();
```

Comment: I thought that was the case, thanks for responding so quickly ;)